# How to target iPad without using browser user agent

Tags: javascript, ipad

I want to target an ipad device in javascript. I know it is possible to do this with user agent string parsing. But this is easy to fake.

I also read that it's better to do a functionality test. like `if(window.matchMedia)` rather than `if (userAgent.indexOf('ipad'))` but still some functions exist in new browsers.

Is there anything that returns the word ipad in the browser ? thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to target iPad specifically? There are plenty of similar devices so discrimination doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: hi thx for ur answer. but feature detection sometimes detect alot of new browsers. it is for a very specific client that want a special function executed for ipad users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, prior to it's deprecation, [navigator.platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform) could have done the job:

```
if( navigator.platform === 'iPad' ){

    // console.log('ipad')

}
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/1029952 for more solutions

Comment: can this be tested in chrome? guess not